# C++ Timer difficulties

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

I'm having issues implementing timing. What i want to do is run this:

```
//relay 1 power cycle
void MainWindow::relay1PCycle()
{
    relay1High();
    while (true){
        QTimer::singleShot(750, this, SLOT(relay1Low()));
        QTimer::singleShot(750, this, SLOT(relay1High()));
    }
}
```

as while a button is pressed.

```
//power cycle button
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_toggled(bool checked)
{
    if (checked){
        //run relay1PCycle as a thread.
    }
    else{
        //Terminate relay1PCycle thread.
    }
}
```

however, so far everything i've tried so far has been a failure.

What's the correct way to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: None of your code creates threads. Try `std::thread`, `std::async` or `QThread` instead.

Comment: The while code is creating multiple timer, since the slot's creation is not blocking.

Comment: @nwp i tried std::thread like so: std::thread t1(relay1PCycle); and i get the error "invalid use of non-static member function"

Qthread i can't get on with at all.

Comment: What does relay1Low do? How long does it take to run relay1Low?

Comment: @eyllanesc it turns off a raspberryPi GPIO pin, which activates a relay. very little time at all

Comment: @eyllanesc - regarding your first comment, the fact that the first bit of code dosen't work had completely escaped my attention but i can fix that. All it's supposed to be doing is alternating the pin between on and off

Comment: as a general addition, i've tried various things and just can't get it to work, I haven't kept a record of all the different attempts, or error messages because i expected to be able to fix it. My problem is that i haven't done any c++ in about 10 years, and can't remember what i'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task they want to implement is not blocking, so it is not necessary to use threads, only a timer with an adequate logic. To make it simple we will assign that task to the next class:

**relaycontroller.h**

```
#ifndef RELAYCONTROLLER_H
#define RELAYCONTROLLER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>

#include <QDebug>

class RelayController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit RelayController(QObject *parent = 0):QObject(parent){
        timer = new QTimer(this);
        state = false;
        timer->setInterval(750);
        //old style
        connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(onTimeout()));
        //new style
        //connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &RelayController::onTimeout);
    }
    void start(){
        qDebug()<<"timer";
        timer->start();
    }
    void stop(){
        timer->stop();
    }

    void relayLow(){
        //code here: relay off
        qDebug()<<"low";
    }
    void relayHigh(){
        //code here: relay on
        qDebug()<<"high";
    }

private slots:

    void onTimeout(){
        if(state)
            relayHigh();
        else
            relayLow();
        state = !state;
    }
private:
    QTimer *timer;
    bool state;
};

#endif // RELAYCONTROLLER_H
```

Then an object is created and used in the slot pressed:

**mainwindow.h**

```
private:
    RelayController *controller;
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    controller = new RelayController(this);
    ui->pushButton_3->setCheckable(true);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_toggled(bool checked)
{
    if(checked)
        controller->start();
    else
        controller->stop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that seems very complicated... and it's giving me multiple errors, starting with:

relaycontroller.h:17: error: ‘void QTimer::timeout()’ is protected
within this context
         connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &RelayController::onTimeout);
                                 ^~~~~~~

it does give me another way of looking at it though. i'll have a deeper look at it, but as i'm coding on the pi itself everything takes ages.

Comment: @Aesgarth I have modified my code, I think it is caused because you have an old version of Qt. I have modified it to be compatible with old versions, if you wish I could help you through teamviewer.

Comment: i'm using qt creator 4.2.0.. and forgive my ignorance but how does teamviewer work?(edit to add, based on QT 5.7.1)

Comment: @Aesgarth It is a service similar to Skype where I can control a PC remotely, then I could write the code for you and you would see what I do, you can suspend the service when you want, it is safe, install it on your PC and notices

Comment: thanks again, OK, your code now compiles, but it seems to only turn the pin off, not cycle on and off... i've uploaded the whole project to www.aesgarth.co.uk/project.zip if you'd be kind enough to have a look at it and see if you can see what i'm trying to do.

Comment: @Aesgarth I see that your GUI for each relay has 4 buttons, what is the function of ON, OFF, POWER CYCLE, HEAT CYCLE?

Comment: ON and OFF simply turn a gpio pin on and off. power cycle should turn the pin on and off with a 750 ms delay, heat cycle should turn the pin on for 2 hours, then off for 30 minutes

Comment: pins will be numbered 0-6, i've been working with pin 2 for testing as i have a multimeter attached to that to monitor the output

Comment: Okay I understand, I'm improving your code to make it easier, I do not have a raspberry at hand right now so I'll need your help to see if it works. Wait a moment and I'll pass the corrected code.

Comment: Thank you! Excellent, that works, now i need to work out how so i understand it.

Comment: @Aesgarth I recommend reading about C ++, so that you do not put it for 10 years, do not program it, then read a bit of Qt and understand the logic, GUI type applications do not use structured programming, use object oriented programming + event-oriented programming GUIs do not like loops that consume a lot of time, so timers are not blocking.

Comment: OK, i'll try to do that. The next thing i'd like to get it to do is increment the cycles LCD once every time either a power or heat cycle completes (starting from 0 when the button is pressed. can you point me in the direction where i should start looking? Thanks Again

Comment: Here is the code, download it https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/47367656/LampTesterV2

Comment: Thanks, I feel awful that you've basically done this for me. To add the function for the heat cycle button, can i essentially make a copy of relaycontroller.h with different delays in, and replicate the code for the power cycle button?

Comment: I will not do more things, that's your task, goodbye. If you can not task, take a few courses or hire someone to do your job.

Comment: That's fair enough. I don't want you to do it for me, i was simply hoping you could point me in the right direction to do it myself. Thank you for all of your help. Goodbye.